# PDO: could not find driver on localhost ubuntu 18.04

Tags: pdo, find, driver, php

Just a simple PDO test on ubuntu 18.04, php7.2 & Mysql Server version: 5.7.24-0ubuntu0.18.04.1 (Ubuntu):  http://localhost/gino/test_pdo/ gave me an error "could not find driver".

```
I have installed all the appropiate files eg:


  sudo apt-get install php7.2-mysql
  sudo phpenmod pdo_mysql
  sudo service apache2 restart 

    I have also deleted the ; from php.ini file eg:

    ;extension=pdo_firebird
     extension=pdo_mysql
     ;extension=pdo_oci

Also the phpinfo.php file DOES NOT SHOW PDO support for mySQL.
I am at a loss on how to fix this  error "could not find driver"  that shows up on the browser. As you can see from above in the php.ini file shows that the PDO module  is there BUT not in the phpinfo.php file.
```